# How do we select data based on month and year in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle10g

I have did my research and I found that it can be done in MSQL  with

```
SELECT * FROM sales WHERE month(sellDate) = 3 AND YEAR(sellDate) = 2017
```

But when I tried with Oracle , It returns me

```
ORA-00904: "YEAR": invalid identifier
```

Is there any Way I could call data based on month and year in oracle query ?

**Solved**

**Thank you so much , I have also came out with a solution**

This is how I did it .. :)

```
select * from sales where to_char(sell,'MM')='09' AND to_char(sell,'YYYY')='2018';
```

Comment: Did you try `select * from sales where to_char(sell_date, 'MM/YYYY') = '03/2017';` ?

Comment: If you have an index on the date and a lot of data you should use a BETWEEN (use 00:00 1st of month and 00:00 1st of following month)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, input this code in your structure.
Hope this helps.

```
 select * from sales where to_char(sell,'MM')='09' AND to_char(sell,'YYYY')='2018';
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `extract` or `to_char`, but as those are acting on the table column value they will cause every value in the table to be converted for comparison, which is wasteful and prevents any index on that column being used.

It would be better to convert your target year and month to match the data type of the column, and then use a range:

```
SELECT * FROM sales
WHERE sellDate >= date '2017-03-01'
AND sellDate < date '2017-04-01'
```

Or if the year and month are variables (so you can't use a date literal) you can use `to_date()` to convert the year and month to a date, and `add_months()` to find the start of the following month, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM sales
WHERE sellDate >= to_date('2017' || '03', 'YYYYMM')
AND sellDate < add_months(to_date('2017' || '03', 'YYYYMM'), 1)
```

and if you are passed the year and month as numbers instead of strings you can explicitly convert those to string with `to_char`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EXTRACT` to get `month` and `year` from `date`.
For Example

```
SELECT Extract(YEAR
               FROM CURRENT_DATE),
       EXTRACT(MONTH
               FROM CURRENT_DATE)
FROM dual;
```

It will generate result as below.

[image]

So the query you posted in question can be re-written as below.

```
SELECT *
FROM sales
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH
              FROM sellDate) = 3
  AND Extract(YEAR
              FROM sellDate) = 2017;
```

You can check the demo [here](http://rextester.com/LSTE89845)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_char` to get year/month:

```
SELECT * FROM dual WHERE to_char(sysdate,'MM') = 8 AND to_char(sysdate,'YYYY') = 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Extract](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) Please ensure sellDate is a date column or change it to date using to_date

```
SELECT * FROM sales WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH from sellDate) = 3 and EXTRACT(YEAR from sellDate) = 2017;
```